# Can there be a peak between 2 lower high prices in the RSI oscillator and still be considered a divergence?

Tags: stock, trading, tradingview-api

[Regular divergence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHbaH.png)

As can be seen in the image, the RSI shows lower high (marked in black) with a peak between the 2 highs. Similarly, the chart shows higher highs with a peak between them. Considering this, can I still call it a valid regular divergence? I made this conclusion because, I found multiple such scenarios where they followed such criteria and still got fall in price.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Divergence is N consecutive Higher High on price and Lower low on the indicator. If there is any single positive or negative peak between these pivots points then its not considered as divergence.